# Where can I find a list of all existing Hebrew words?

Tags: dictionary, hebrew

I'm a programmer and right now I'm working on a Hebrew translator. It would translate using google translate and would automatically add nekudots in text.

And I'm a bit stuck trying to find a decent Hebrew dictionary. I read in an article that there are about 30-40k words in Hebrew (70-80k including smehuts). If someone somehow has a list of all existing hebrew words it would be really helpful

Comment: I am looking for a corpus of Modern Hebrew verbs. Did you find an answer to this puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether it will help: wikipedia has rather big word frequency lists, but it also includes conjugated forms and no translations.

[Here it is](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists#Hebrew)

Comment: It will be more then enough. Спасибо!